# Smoke viewport Display in 2.81a

Tags: 3d-view, smoke-simulation

Just started to play with smoke in Blender 2.81a, I did not use the Quick Smoke, but start from scratch.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a sphere as Flow object
2. Create a Cube as Domain (sphere is inside Domain)
3. Create a *Principled Volume Shader* and link it to the volume of the sphere

Then press <kbd>Space</kbd> to run the simulation.

In *Layout* tab, I can see the sim only in *Wireframe* or *Shade Mode*, but not in *Material Preview* nor *Render Mode*.

In Blender 2.81a volumetrics seem to be ON by default in the Render Properties, so I don't know why I can't see it in *Render Mode*.

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it, you need to put the shader on the Domain, not the flow object.